# Save a picture from a camera feed in the same path as the js script

Tags: javascript

I'm using vs code to run a local server that uses the faceapi JavaScript library to detect faces in a video stream from the user's camera. It loads the necessary models for face detection and displays the real-time video with detected faces on a canvas element. It also provides a button to capture a screenshot of the video stream with detected faces and save it as a PNG file. The image file will be saved in automatically in the downloads folder. Is there a way to save the captured image in the same directory as the JavaScript file.

```
const screenshotButton = document.getElementById('screenshotButton');

Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')
]).then(startVideo);

function startVideo() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    { video: {} },
    stream => video.srcObject = stream,
    err => console.error(err)
  );
}

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);
  document.body.append(canvas);
  const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height };
  faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
  setInterval(async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
  }, 100);

  screenshotButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
    if (detections.length > 0) {
      const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);
      document.body.append(canvas);
      const displaySize = { width: video.width, height: video.height };
      faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
      const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
      canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = `screenshot-${new Date().toISOString()}.png`;
      link.href = dataURL;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
      document.body.removeChild(canvas); // Remove the canvas after taking the screenshot
    } else {
      alert('No face detected in the video. Please position your face in front of the camera and try again.');
    }
  });
});
```